# Big size of images after merging in Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

these are my first projects in python and I am doing this as a hobby. I try to do my best providing Code and explanation of my problem.

In my scientific work I am often working with plots that have to be combined into one figure. Most of my colleagues are using CorelDraw or some other software for it but it is a pain if you add a new plot somewhere in the middle and then you have to change all picutres and labels.

I thought there should be an easy way, loading all images into a python program, labeling them with a letter, then combining them and then saving them as a new image. My first attempt was in replit and it worked well. Now I tried to use streamlit and github to make an UI for it so my coleagues can use it as well.

But somehow I ended up with much bigger pictures than previously (big in terms of file size). Each plot is exported from origin as a tif file with around 50kb 300dpi on 3.5 inches. I use 3-8 plots for one figure.
When I combine them and even after scaling them down to 1050pixels width they have multiple MB.
What makes this even more confusing is, that I can use this windows photo program and click "scale down image". Then I choose 100% for scaling so no change in size but it is now 500kb. Even when I zoom in, there is no change visible.

In my replit I draged all tifs into one folder and then loaded them into a variable.

In Streamlit I used the st.file_uploader for uploading the images. Then they are stored in a variable. From that I created a new folder and stored all the images there.
Then I could use the same code I used in replit.
5 picutres each 50kb ended up in a 15MB file.

Then I skipped the "saving in a seperate folder" because I thought maybe every save/load makes it bigger.
So I opened the images straigth up from the variable and my file is now 5MB.

I know from latex that everyone is asking for a minimum working example which seems a little bit dificult because I do not know which step of the process is the problem.
But I tried to provide the main code without all the functions and some description to it. If anything more is needed I am happy to provide it.
Here is the full code in the git repository
https://github.com/VonClaussen/image-orientation

And the streamlit App
https://image-orientation.streamlit.app/

```
import streamlit as st
#here are more imports like PIL, io,  

#upload images
uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Upload Files", type=["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "tif"], accept_multiple_files=True)

#Load the uploaded files into the variable
image_list = []  # Initialize an empty list to store the uploaded images
filename_list=[]
if uploaded_files:
    for file in uploaded_files:
        # Read the image file and append it to the list
        image_data = file.read()
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
        image_list.append(image)
        filename_list.append(file.name)
        st.write(f"Opened file: {file.name}")

if st.button('Build figure'):
    # First all images get a label. label info stores all information like font, size, shift of the label etc.
    labeled_images = label_images(image_list, label_info)

    #now the labeled images are handed over to the drawing setup. From the number of images it calculates which images goes into which row/column and returns two variables.
    # row_list stores multiple lists, one for each row. Each list contains the labeled images that go into this row.
    # column_list is like row_list but stores the images of a column.
    row_list, column_list = drawing_setup(labeled_images, number_of_rows,
                                        number_of_columns)
    # the get_dimensions function iterates through all images in a row to termine the max height of that row which is stored in the dictionary max-height with the row index as a key
    # max_widths is the same dictionary for the max width of each column
    #total_height and total_width store the maximum dimensions to create the new image.
    max_heights, max_widths, total_height, total_width = get_dimensions(
        row_list, column_list)
    #final image iterates through the row list. It pastes all the images according to the coordinates that are calculated from max_height and max_width for each image
    final_image = arange_images(row_list, max_heights, max_widths, total_height, total_width, background_color)
    #The following step will reduce the size of the image usally to 3.5 or 7 inch at 300dpi
    small_image=fx.resize(final_image, reduced_width)
    small_image.save('small_image.tif')
    
    #Finally the new image can be downloaded
    with open("small_image.tif", "rb") as file:
      btn = st.download_button(
            label="Download image",
            data=file,
            file_name="small_image.tif",
            mime="image/tif"
          )
```

Comment: I would imagine your original TIFFs are compressed in some way, or have a different color mode. If you have ImageMagick installed, you can try `identify *.tif` on them and compare the result to the bigger TIFF you get.

Comment: Problem is, I am doing this from work and I can not install software but I might try this at home.

Comment: Well, you can also see what `Pillow` thinks of the images. You evidently do have it installed :)

Comment: Ah ok sorry we are talking about packages in python. Yes thats why I use Git/replit because then I can do everything in the browser.

Comment: ImageMagick isn't a Python package, but anyway: to figure out why your source images are much smaller than the resulting composition image, you'll need to take a close technical look at them, and IM's `identify` is a good tool for that.

Comment: What happened when you didn't combine/modify multiple images but just loaded and saved one without modifications? Did the size grow a lot as well, or did it remain about the same?

Comment: Do you have libtiff and its headers installed like [Pillow's TiFF documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#tiff) says?

Comment: I read that and tried it this morning. Problem is, pip install libtiff is not working in the codespace. 
I opened up a new question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77357963/how-to-install-libtiff-in-codespace
When this is solved maybe I can provide more info or an answer to this topic

Answer (score 0):

for the sizes you are describing, this can only mean tifs are being saved with no compression at all - that is, each pixel takes a full 32bit on the output file.

Just check PIL `.save` options for saving tiff files, LZW compression will give you lossless files, and with a reasonable size. Or just save then as `.png`, which are compressed by default.

Here, I passed in the `compression='tiff_lzw'` option when saving the tiff, and my 1024x768 image went from more than 3MB to 70KB.

```
In [15]: img.save("test.tif")

In [16]: !ls -l test.tif
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jsbueno jsbueno 3146566 Nov 25 15:41 test.tif

In [17]: img.save("test.tif", compression="tiff_lzw")

In [18]: !ls -l test.tif
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jsbueno jsbueno 74044 Nov 25 15:43 test.tif
```

Unfortunately, the documentation for Pillow is hard to read for some subjects, and even for the above, I could only get the tif compression options by looking at the source code.

So, for convenience of other people getting here, these are they:

```
COMPRESSION_INFO = {
    # Compression => pil compression name
    1: "raw",
    2: "tiff_ccitt",
    3: "group3",
    4: "group4",
    5: "tiff_lzw",
    6: "tiff_jpeg",  # obsolete
    7: "jpeg",
    8: "tiff_adobe_deflate",
    32771: "tiff_raw_16",  # 16-bit padding
    32773: "packbits",
    32809: "tiff_thunderscan",
    32946: "tiff_deflate",
    34676: "tiff_sgilog",
    34677: "tiff_sgilog24",
    34925: "lzma",
    50000: "zstd",
    50001: "webp",
}
```

Comment: You can also find the compression options in the documentation I linked to (in the "Saving" section).